# Make whole <li> as link using CSS

Tags: html, css

I've tried doing the below but the result is not satisfactory. I want to cover the whole tab as a link but only the part in red becomes link. I want to expand the red border to the entire tab but don't know how to do it. Changing padding size results in the expansion of the tab along with the red border.

**CSS**

```
.tabed .tabs li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid #F00 2px;
```

Here is the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/XingPing/j8zgrnev/

Comment: remove padding on li and add a{display: block;}

Comment: Move `padding` from `li` to `a`

Comment: It worked! Thanks Luka & Usman. :)